# Save all terminal input and output as PDF (more than 200 pages)

Tags: macos, terminal, pdf, printing

I used Terminal on Mac to do some bioinformatics analysis. I'd like to save all my input and output as PDF. I could do it using:

*Shell* → *Print Selection* → *PDF* → *Save As PDF*

or:

*Shell* → *Export Selected Text As…*.

Since my output has many pages (more than 300 pages), the default printer would save only the first 224 pages as PDF.

So, I was wondering if could revise some settings and save all my 300 pages text as PDF.

Comment: And "Export as text" (cmd-S) first into a file and print the file (maybe after splitting or editing it) doesn't helps?

Comment: What you need isn't in `.bash_history`?

Comment: @Raystafarian Because .bash_history just gives me the input command lines, I'd like to save **both** the input and output.

Comment: Would it be ok to loose the SDTERR output?

Answer (score 1):

If you still have this terminal open, you can

1. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all the text in the window
2. <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy it
3. open text edit
4. <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste in all the text you copied

Then use print + save as pdf from there